# FTP Deleted Folder keeps reappearing

Tags: wordpress, ftp, file-permissions

I have the following WP site hosted under mediatemple:

http://actividades.acropolis.org.mx.s160231.gridserver.com/actividades

(the way it is set up (I didn't do it, I was just tasked to migrate the site over from a crappier host) is that the actividades page becomes the index/home page of the site)

Everything was nice and dandy until yesterday when suddenly, out of nowhere, the old folder /actividades/ (that I had deleted hours before) which shares the same name as the pagename... recreated itself.

This leads to having:

http://actividades.acropolis.org.mx.s160231.gridserver.com/actividades/

Since the apache modrewrite name of the page matches the folder name...it conflicts. To make matters worse, the folder gets 750 permissions instead of 755 which doesn't let .htaccess and apache get into it. If I fix the permissions, you do enter the folder but get the classical (index file not found) crap.

Index page or not, I don't give a damn about the folder...its conflictive and needs to be gone forever...

So I deleted it, fixed the issue and noticed it remade itself 5 seconds later.

I've tried everything, googled everything and there does not seem to be any answer from either a server-side viewpoint nor a wordpress angle.

So broken and defeated I come to you experts for words of wisdom.

Comment: ¿Are you sure it is not a symlink and does it have the original content when it reappears?

Comment: symlink?

The folder... when I first deleted it, had many subfolders and files.
Right now, when it re-appears, it only has one of the original folders inside it, with its respective subfolders, but there is not a single file within any of them.

Comment: There must be a script somewhere that recreates that sub-directory structure. It is not a symlink ( Symbolic link) though,  as the content would be also mirrored.

Comment: i gave up and deleted everything =/

Comment: Well, that's one way to solve the problem. Another one could have been searching for the URI string inside all scripts, with the ISP or your FTP application. It could take some time, though. Good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugins installed on this particular wp site turned out to have some info stored in them that kept the former location they were in, in this case the folder /actividades/ before i even began working on the site.

So someone moved them via ftp out of the /actividades/ folder and into the root which did not update the path in which these plugins record their images and data and blabla so they kept remaking the folders...

I deleted the core wp files then the wp content folder and then the remainder of the site and went for a clean re-install.

Given the messy php nature of wordpress itself, not to mention that of its plugins... it was simpler this way. Locating the precise script that triggered the folder recreation was out of my league.